# Configuring ssl apache in Redhat linux

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, p7b

I have one apache server which is configured with ssl.

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/certs/localhost.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/private/localhost.key
```

Now i need to replace the certificate with a new one(Provided by our department).
For that i have shared the csr and they send back the certificate.

Now the file that they have shared is *.p7b (contains the certificate in PEM/base64 encoded format. is a .p7b file with the DER encoded certificate and the issuing CA certificate.)

But in apache ssl.conf i need to provide the crt file. How to get the crt files from p7b

Answer (score 1):

Install openssl on Red Hat Linux server / CentOS 7

1. Firstly we need to install httpd on our server, to install httpd type the below command,
   yum install httpd
2. After installing httpd, Now we need to install mod_ssl,
   yum install mod_ssl
3. Now, we have install openssl as well on the server,
   yum install openssl
4. After installing httpd, mod_ssl & openssl, we need to generate key using below command,
   openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
5. openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr  (You can skip steps by pressing enter)
6. openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca.cert
7. cp ca.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs
8. cp ca.key /etc/pki/tls/private/
9. cp ca.csr /etc/pki/tls/private
10. vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt

Replace by

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
```

and

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

Replace by

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key


  11. httpd -t (check whether the above change are correct or not)

  12. vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Go to the bottom of the file and write

<VirtaulHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
    servername localhost
    Documentroot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
Save & Exit

 13. httpd -t (check whether the above change are correct or not)

 14. firewall-cmd –permanent –add-service=https

 15. firewall-cmd –permanent –add-port=443/tcp

 16. firewall-cmd  --reload

 17. service httpd restart
```